# Complex Array strange behaviour

Tags: c#, arrays

In the example below, I found a strange behaviour.
I'm initializing a matrix of Complex (using `System.Numerics`), assigning a counter value for each position.
But at a certain moment the procedure override the previous cells.

What's wrong there is there any array limit? 
it seems the Complex type the issue, with a double array this doesn't happen.

Any suggestion?

```
private static void Test()
    {
        Complex[,] m = new Complex[16400, 16400]; 
        long count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16400; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16400; j++)
            {
                m[i, j] = new Complex((double)count++, 0);

                if (m[0,0] != 1)
                    Debug.Print(string.Format("({0},{1})>  m[0,0] =" + m[0, 0].ToString(), i,j));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Complex equals scalar? m[0,0] != 1

Comment: @ThomasWeller I assume `Complex` overrides the `=` operator.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Or as the [docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259536(v=vs.110).aspx) there's an implicit conversion.

Comment: Perhaps the problem here is that you are trying to create almost 300 million instances of an object and you're running out of contiguous memory...

Comment: I got an `OutOfMemoryException` on your array intialization, but once I reduce the size the code seems to behave as expected.

Comment: What is "a certain moment"? Is it time related? Is it index related? What does "override" mean? Which value is overridden?

Comment: Same for me: "Array dimensions exceeded supported range.". Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: I'm compiling in x64 platform with VS2015.

Comment: <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>

Comment: with that setting I can go over 2GB

Comment: Your array is over 4GB in size though, do you have 4GB of **contiguous** memory available?

Comment: I have 24GB of RAM how can ensure the continuosity. Is it possible? is this the problem?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/

Comment: Go read that article. I would seriously question if you really need to create all those instances at the same time though.

Comment: In my case yes I need this space but if there are these limits I will change approach.

Comment: In order to respond to Thomas. Override means overwrite (sorry). At certain moment means at [16384,245] it beging to overwrite.